# Is there a way to condense this into fewer lines? HTML

Tags: javascript, html

My code that I'd like to condense:

```
document.getElementById("costA").innerHTML = currentCost[0];
document.getElementById("costB").innerHTML = currentCost[1];
document.getElementById("costC").innerHTML = currentCost[2];
document.getElementById("costD").innerHTML = currentCost[3];
document.getElementById("costE").innerHTML = currentCost[4];
document.getElementById("costF").innerHTML = currentCost[5];
document.getElementById("costG").innerHTML = currentCost[6];
document.getElementById("costH").innerHTML = currentCost[7];
document.getElementById("amountA").innerHTML = building[0];
document.getElementById("amountB").innerHTML = building[1];
document.getElementById("amountC").innerHTML = building[2];
document.getElementById("amountD").innerHTML = building[3];
document.getElementById("amountE").innerHTML = building[4];
document.getElementById("amountF").innerHTML = building[5];
document.getElementById("amountG").innerHTML = building[6];
document.getElementById("amountH").innerHTML = building[7];
document.getElementById("bonusA").innerHTML = currentBonuses[0];
document.getElementById("bonusB").innerHTML = currentBonuses[1];
document.getElementById("bonusC").innerHTML = currentBonuses[2];
document.getElementById("bonusD").innerHTML = currentBonuses[3];
document.getElementById("bonusE").innerHTML = currentBonuses[4];
document.getElementById("bonusF").innerHTML = currentBonuses[5];
document.getElementById("bonusG").innerHTML = currentBonuses[6];
document.getElementById("bonusH").innerHTML = currentBonuses[7];
```

I see three main sections that look like they can be condensed. I'd also, perhaps, prefer a way to be able to add or subtract an arbitrary number of buildings without changing too much of the code.

Comment: Of course, it's possible (loops are wonderful invention), but why you ended up with such IDs at the first place? At least you can change them into `cost0`, `cost1` etc.

Comment: I'm doing it because I have many outputs. If you want to see the current state of my (buggy) program, here: http://truenachtara.github.io/test-incremental/index.html Everything is supposed to have an output on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can update in a loop. Following is a very basic representation:

```
var alphabetArr = ["A", "B","C","D","E","F","G","H"];

alphabetArr.forEach(function(row, i){
  document.getElementById("cost" + row).innerHTML = currentCost[i]; 
  document.getElementById("amount" + row).innerHTML = building[i];
  document.getElementById("bonus" + row).innerHTML = currentBonuses[i]; 
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, here is another way to do it without hard coding an array of letters. Another benefit is that this avoids `Array.prototype.forEach` which is not available in Internet Explorer 8

```
var start = "A".charCodeAt(0);
var end = "H".charCodeAt(0);

for (var i = start; i <= end; i += 1) {
  var row = String.fromCharCode(i);
  document.getElementById('cost' + row).innerHTML = currentCost[i - start];
  document.getElementById('amount' + row).innerHTML = building[i - start];
  document.getElementById('bonus' + row).innerHTML = currentBonuses[i - start];
}
```